# DirectShow ISampleGrabberCB stops after Ctrl+Alt+Del

Tags: .net, directshow, samplegrabber

I have created and rendered a directshow graph. The graph itself is being rendered into a `ISampleGrabberCB` and all is well.

However, if I press Ctrl+Alt+Del, the `BufferCB` on the `ISampleGrabberCB` stops getting called. I have checked the graph and it is still running. Why did `ISampleGrabberCB` stop working?

Comment: Whatever the cause is, it is not related to Sample Grabber itself. If you have a renderer there in chain, most likely it loses surfaces and affects the whole graph.

Comment: To narrow this down you could trying using the null renderer and see if the behaviour is the same. You could also try building the sample grabber filter from MSDN samples to debug this in more detail.